# Thread stops its job

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I have file listener which monitor changes in file. I want this app to work parallelly. When I do `/follow` I'm creatind thread which monitor given file. Then I'm doing second `/follow` to monitor another file. It works only for 2,3 saves for each file. After few changes in file it looks like thread which follows the file is killed.
In `listener` method I looped the thread to start watching the same file again

My `FileController`

```
public class FileController {
    private final FileService fileService;
@PostMapping("/follow")
    public ResponseEntity startFollowFile(@RequestBody PathModel path) throws Exception {
        return fileService.fileFollower(path.getPath());
    }
```

My `FileService` class

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FileService {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("fixedThreadPool")
    private final ExecutorService executorService;


    public ResponseEntity fileFollower(String pathProvided) throws Exception {
        File f = new File(pathProvided);
        if (f.isFile()) {
            List<Future<List<String>>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

            futures.add(executorService.submit(new MonitorChangesTask(pathProvided)));


            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);

} else {
            throw new FileNotExist(pathProvided);
        }
    }
}
```

My `MonitorChangesTask` class

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MonitorChangesTask implements Callable {
    private final String pathProvided;

@Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        String s1 = pathProvided.replaceAll("\\\\", " ");
        String[] split = s1.split(" ");
        StringBuilder directory = new StringBuilder();
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < split.length - 1; i++) {
            String s = split[counter];
            counter++;
            directory.append(s).append("\\");
        }
        listener(split, directory);
        return new Object();
}

 private void listener(String[] split, StringBuilder directory) throws Exception {
        Path path = Path.of(directory.toString());
        try (final WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService()) {
            final WatchKey watchKey = path.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);
            while (true) {
                final WatchKey wk = watchService.take();
                for (WatchEvent<?> event : wk.pollEvents()) {
                    final Path changed = (Path) event.context();


 if (changed.endsWith(split[split.length - 1])) {
                        call();

 }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Why it stops following file after few saves of file? Something must be wrong with looping.

Comment: `call()` calls `listener()` but `listener()` calls `call()`; that's definitely bad; I notice you are using `ResponseEntity` and `Callable` as raw types, returning `new Object()` for some reason, you use `replaceAll` instead of `replace` but you aren't using a regex, you change the backslashes to spaces, then put them back, apparently to get the basename of the path? you have a `counter` that just tracks the value of the loop index `i`, and you add one future to a list of futures which then immediately goes out of scope. These are all... areas for improvement.

Comment: Just to narrow in on one thing: `Callable<V>` is a generic type. You should never be declaring anything to be a callable, but rather, callable-of-something. Callable-of-Integer (`Callable<Integer>`), or callable-of-list-of-string (`Callable<List<String>>`), and then returning that type, and then doing something with it somewhere else. If you don't want to return anything or do anything with it, just use `Runnable`. The executor service will happily take a runnable task to perform.